# Doctrine associations owning vs inverse side

Tags: php, database, hibernate, symfony, doctrine-orm

In the Doctrine Association [reference manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) it's mentioned that

> Of course, in a correct application the semantics of the bidirectional association are properly maintained by the application developer (that’s his responsibility)

I haven't been able to find a concrete example on how the developer should maintain this association. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really good example in the symfony documentation about this: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Around the middle of the page is is stated that:

> A second potential issue deals with the [Owning Side and Inverse Side](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)
>   of Doctrine relationships. In this example, if the "owning" side of
>   the relationship is "Task", then persistence will work fine as the
>   tags are properly added to the Task. However, if the owning side is on
>   "Tag", then you'll need to do a little bit more work to ensure that
>   the correct side of the relationship is modified.

In this particular example, the doctrine documentation you mentioned would relate to this part of the entities code:

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Entity/Task.php

// ...
public function addTag(ArrayCollection $tag)
{
    $tag->addTask($this);

    $this->tags->add($tag);
}
```

and

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Entity/Tag.php

// ...
public function addTask(Task $task)
{
    if (!$this->tasks->contains($task)) {
        $this->tasks->add($task);
    }
}
```